# how to display users under a group in a line for each user in Linux bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, tr

Currently when I run a grep command on a visitors group that I had created

```
grep visitors:x:1011: /etc/group
```

This is a sample result of the above command, as the actual result is too long.

```
visitors:x:1011:ellipsiscoterie,magnetcommonest,wizardmeans,beakskeletal,lemonwellmade,ralphpaperclips etc..
```

How do I display the above result as shown below (without visitors:x:1101 and separating the commas), as I have difficulty doing so.

```
ellipsiscoterie
magnetcommonest
wizardmeans
beakskeletal
lemonwellmade
ralphpaperclips
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest using `sed` instead of `grep`

```
sed -n -e 's/^visitors\:x\:1011\://p' /etc/group | tr ',' '\n'
```

UPD: detailed explain of `sed` part is [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24151). `tr` examples you can find [here](https://www.tecmint.com/tr-command-examples-in-linux/)

Answer (score 4):

Using awk, you can set the field separated to a colon using `-F:` and check if the string starts with `visitors:x:1011:`

As the comma separated values always seems to be at the end, split the last field `$NF` on a comma and loop the splitted values.

```
awk -F: '
/^visitors:x:1011:/ {
  count=split($NF, ary, ",");
  for(i=1; i<=count; i++) print ary[i];
}' /etc/group
```

Answer (score 3):

A good approach to query groups and users is making use of the `getent` command as it also works on ldap systems.

```
$ getent group visitors | cut -d: -f4 | tr ',' '\n'
```

On standard systems this will always work as usernames and groupnames cannot contain the <comma>-character or the <colon>-character. (If you have a non-standard Linux or Unix system, see  `man useradd` and `man groupadd` to check the username and group name rules)

If you want to use `awk` instead of this little pipeline, then an elegant—but cryptic—version would read:

```
$ getent group visitors | awk -F: '{FS=",";OFS=ORS;$0=$4;$1=$1}1'
```

Comment: I wish I had thought of `getent` when I wrote my answer. I'd still use `awk` to parse the output though, but still, `getent` seems like the appropriate tool for this.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm also a big fan of awk, however one should not underestimate the efficiency of piping and those optimized atomic tools that can do one thing very well (cut, paste, tr, join, ...). awk is a bit of a sledgehammer for a task like this

Comment: :-) True. It's not the tools. It's the extra process and pipe I'd like to avoid, but in reality, it probably won't matter much. I _really_ like your `awk` version! Wish I could upvote it one more time.

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` program.

```
awk -F':' '/^visitors:x:1011/ && NF==4{gsub(/,/,ORS,$4);print $4}' /etc/group
```

***OR*** in case entry `visitors:x:1011` comes only once in your file then try following:

```
awk -F':' '/^visitors:x:1011/ && NF==4{gsub(/,/,ORS,$4);print $4;exit}' /etc/group
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, making field separator as `:` for all lines. Then in main program, checking condition if line starts from `visitors:x:1011` and number of fields are 4 then globally substitute comma with new line(ORS) in 4th field and print it.

---

---

***OR*** if line with `visitors:x:1011` comes once and 4th field is NULL(means no entry present which is obvious in some cases) and you want to print message for it then try following:

`awk -F':' '/^visitors:x:1011/ && NF==4{if($4==""){print "NO entry found in /etc/group"} else{gsub(/,/,ORS,$4);print $4};exit}' /etc/group`

Answer (score 1):

One option could be to use `awk`:

```
awk -F: '$1 == "visitors" {
    size = split($4, users, ",");
    for(i=1; i<=size; ++i) print users[i];
    exit }' /etc/group
```

- `-F:` - Use `:` as the field separator
- `$1 == "visitors"` - If the first field matches `visitors` execute the following statement (within `{` ... `}`)
- `size = split($4, users, ",");` - Split the 4:th field on `,` and store the result in the array `users`. Returns the number of elements in `users` and puts that in `size`.
- The `for` loop - Loop over all the elements in `users` and print them out.
- `exit` - Terminate `awk` - There's no need to continue reading the rest of the file.

Answer (score 0):

If the result of `grep visitors:x:1011: /etc/group` is a text line:

`visitors:x:1011:ellipsiscoterie,magnetcommonest,wizardmeans,beakskeletal,lemonwellmade,ralphpaperclips`

you could try this `awk`:

```
awk '/^visitors:/ {sub(/([^:]+:)+/,"");gsub(/,/, ORS)} 1' file
ellipsiscoterie
magnetcommonest
wizardmeans
beakskeletal
lemonwellmade
ralphpaperclips
```

- initial regexp: if the line matches `visitors:` at the beginning, do the following.
- the action: eliminate all characters till last `:` using `sub()` and then substitute, using `gsub()`, all commas by the default value of `ORS`.